# What is the appropriate number of threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gcc, pthreads

I create `N` threads using `pthread_create` on Linux/gcc. Each thread writes using `for (;;) printf(...)` its ID as fast as it can, nothing else. I let the whole program run for 3 seconds using `usleep` and notice that on my `4-core` CPU when `N=4` it produces something around 1,000,000 lines and when `N=8` it produces around 4 times as much. What is the reason that on 4-core CPU 8 threads perform better? CPU doesn't have hyperthreading enabled.

Comment: I/O operations, hyperthreading, lots of things.

Comment: @MarcoMariani No, hyperthreading is not available.

Comment: but you are using blocking I/O, aren't you? so your threads are idle while the peripherials work and the cpu is waiting for them

Comment: I have observed in several occasions that IO operations can benefit for a higher number of threads, which is surprising since computation shouldn't be the bottleneck. If anyone knows why, I am also interested.

Comment: A suggestion: Take the display out of the equation by redirecting output to `/dev/null`. See how things change.

Comment: @Ben - preemptive multitaskers have one, big advantage to balance out all the problems with synchro, etc - I/O performance is very good because a thread can made ready as soon as the driver it is waiting on requires service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I/O and CPU operations are very different. If you run CPU-intensive computations, N=number of cores will be optimal. For I/O, the optimal number can be far higher.

Comment: +1. However - *"For I/O, the optimal number can be far higher."* - Or, it can be far lower. Really depends on I/O throughput.

Comment: But why is that the optimal number of threads is higher for IOs ?

Comment: Suppose your I/O operations are blocking reads on network sockets. Each task can be blocked for seconds, but once the data arrives, processing can be very fast. Thus you machine can handle far more connections than it has cores, but since each operation is blocking, you will need a lot of threads to handle them all simultaneously.

Comment: ..but it's a printf() loop!  A simple operation on an output stream that surely has to be locked up with a mutex to allow multi threads to output to the same stream.   8 threads should not be faster than 4.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have one thread running on each core if you have 4threads. Neither 2 with 8threads.
The idea of multi core is to separate the work achieved. Moreover, you are achieving a light CPU work by just displaying the thread ID. Hence, it is not using your CPU capacities but the ability of handle display events.

Comment: "*you wont have on thread running on each core*" Why not ? At least this  is possible if you bind threads to processors.